# Clicking on wordpress link first time does not work

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

My links in a Wordpress post do not work correctly the first time they are clicked. They redirect to some other location on the same page. However if I go back and click them a second time they work correctly and goto the referred site or perform a download as intended. I am using WordPress 4.9.6 running Twenty Seventeen theme. I have installed the Broken Link Checker plugin and it says all links are okay.

Comment: You can see the problem on the blog at nfcbeast.com

Comment: The links are working fine for me first time only.

Comment: Vivek, Thank you for checking. Maybe it is only on my side. Thanks.